# Cannot align amsmath equations in multicol to the left

Tags: amsmath, multicol

I'm trying to create a simple cheat sheet using Latex. I'm using multicol to segment the page and the equations on each column.

However, the equations are not aligned to the left despite using `flalign` and because of the font size, they are cut off by the multicol separator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{multicol, amsmath, geometry}
    \geometry{
      a4paper,
      margin = 0.4in
    }
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{multicols*}{3}
    \begin{center}
      \textbf{Logical Equivalences}
    \end{center}
    \small
    \begin{flalign*}
      P \wedge T \equiv P\\
      P \vee F \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee T \equiv T\\
      P \wedge F \equiv F\\\\    
      P \wedge P \equiv P\\
      P \vee P \equiv P\\\\ 
      \neg (\neg P) \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee Q \equiv Q \vee P\\
      P \wedge Q \equiv Q \wedge P\\\\
      (P \vee Q) \vee R \equiv P \vee (Q \vee R)\\
      (P \wedge Q) \wedge R \equiv P \wedge (Q \wedge R)\\\\
      P \vee (Q \wedge R) \equiv (P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R)\\
      P \wedge (Q \vee R) \equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge R)\\\\
      \neg (P \wedge Q) \equiv \neg P \vee \neg Q\\
      \neg (P \vee Q) \equiv \neg P \wedge \neg Q\\\\  
      P \vee (P \wedge Q) \equiv P\\
      P \wedge (P \vee Q) \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee \neg P \equiv T\\
      P \wedge \neg P \equiv F\\\\ 
      P \implies Q \equiv \neg P \vee Q\\
      P \implies Q \equiv \neg Q \implies \neg Q\\
      P \vee Q \equiv \neg P \implies Q\\
      P \wedge Q \equiv \neg (P \implies \neg Q)\\
      \neg (P \implies Q) \equiv P \wedge \neg Q\\
      (P \implies Q) \wedge (P \implies R) \equiv P \implies (Q \wedge R)\\
      (P \implies Q) \vee (P \implies R) \equiv P \implies (Q \vee R)\\
      (P \implies R) \wedge (P \implies R) \equiv (P \vee Q)\implies R\\
      (P \implies R) \vee (P \implies R) \equiv (P \wedge Q)\implies R\\\\
      P \iff Q \equiv (P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies P)\\
      P \iff Q \equiv \neg P \iff \neg \neg Q\\
      P \iff Q \equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg Q \wedge \neg P)\\
      \neg (P \iff Q) \equiv P \iff \neg Q         
    \end{flalign*}
  \end{multicols*}

  \end{document}
```

I tried using `\small` to reduce the size of the equations but they still don't fit. Is there a way to have them aligned left and dynamically sized to the margins of the multicols?

Comment: Off-topic: In the third-to-last row, is `P \iff Q \equiv \neg P \iff \neg \neg Q` correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`flalign` is not designed to align to the left: use the `[fleqn]` option to the package (or documentclass) to get left aligned equations. Also the first cell in an alignment structure is aligned to the right so either use an un-aligned environment such as `gather` or use `&\equiv` to align the equivalences.

So like this, except that the lines are still too wide

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

  \usepackage{multicol, amsmath, geometry}
    \geometry{
      a4paper,
      margin = 0.4in
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{multicols*}{3}
    \begin{center}
      \textbf{Logical Equivalences}
    \end{center}
    \small
    \begin{gather*}
      P \wedge T \equiv P\\
      P \vee F \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee T \equiv T\\
      P \wedge F \equiv F\\\\    
      P \wedge P \equiv P\\
      P \vee P \equiv P\\\\ 
      \neg (\neg P) \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee Q \equiv Q \vee P\\
      P \wedge Q \equiv Q \wedge P\\\\
      (P \vee Q) \vee R \equiv P \vee (Q \vee R)\\
      (P \wedge Q) \wedge R \equiv P \wedge (Q \wedge R)\\\\
      P \vee (Q \wedge R) \equiv (P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R)\\
      P \wedge (Q \vee R) \equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge R)\\\\
      \neg (P \wedge Q) \equiv \neg P \vee \neg Q\\
      \neg (P \vee Q) \equiv \neg P \wedge \neg Q\\\\  
      P \vee (P \wedge Q) \equiv P\\
      P \wedge (P \vee Q) \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee \neg P \equiv T\\
      P \wedge \neg P \equiv F\\\\ 
      P \implies Q \equiv \neg P \vee Q\\
      P \implies Q \equiv \neg Q \implies \neg Q\\
      P \vee Q \equiv \neg P \implies Q\\
      P \wedge Q \equiv \neg (P \implies \neg Q)\\
      \neg (P \implies Q) \equiv P \wedge \neg Q\\
      (P \implies Q) \wedge (P \implies R) \equiv P \implies (Q \wedge R)\\
      (P \implies Q) \vee (P \implies R) \equiv P \implies (Q \vee R)\\
      (P \implies R) \wedge (P \implies R) \equiv (P \vee Q)\implies R\\
      (P \implies R) \vee (P \implies R) \equiv (P \wedge Q)\implies R\\\\
      P \iff Q \equiv (P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies P)\\
      P \iff Q \equiv \neg P \iff \neg \neg Q\\
      P \iff Q \equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg Q \wedge \neg P)\\
      \neg (P \iff Q) \equiv P \iff \neg Q         
    \end{gather*}
  \end{multicols*}

  \end{document}
```

This version fits, if you have good eyesight...

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

  \usepackage{multicol, amsmath, geometry}
    \geometry{
      a4paper,
      margin = 0.4in
    }
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.4in}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{multicols*}{3}
    \begin{center}
      \textbf{Logical Equivalences}
    \end{center}
    \tiny
    \begin{gather*}
      P \wedge T \equiv P\\
      P \vee F \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee T \equiv T\\
      P \wedge F \equiv F\\\\    
      P \wedge P \equiv P\\
      P \vee P \equiv P\\\\ 
      \neg (\neg P) \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee Q \equiv Q \vee P\\
      P \wedge Q \equiv Q \wedge P\\\\
      (P \vee Q) \vee R \equiv P \vee (Q \vee R)\\
      (P \wedge Q) \wedge R \equiv P \wedge (Q \wedge R)\\\\
      P \vee (Q \wedge R) \equiv (P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R)\\
      P \wedge (Q \vee R) \equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge R)\\\\
      \neg (P \wedge Q) \equiv \neg P \vee \neg Q\\
      \neg (P \vee Q) \equiv \neg P \wedge \neg Q\\\\  
      P \vee (P \wedge Q) \equiv P\\
      P \wedge (P \vee Q) \equiv P\\\\
      P \vee \neg P \equiv T\\
      P \wedge \neg P \equiv F\\\\ 
      P \implies Q \equiv \neg P \vee Q\\
      P \implies Q \equiv \neg Q \implies \neg Q\\
      P \vee Q \equiv \neg P \implies Q\\
      P \wedge Q \equiv \neg (P \implies \neg Q)\\
      \neg (P \implies Q) \equiv P \wedge \neg Q\\
      (P \implies Q) \wedge (P \implies R) \equiv P \implies (Q \wedge R)\\
      (P \implies Q) \vee (P \implies R) \equiv P \implies (Q \vee R)\\
      (P \implies R) \wedge (P \implies R) \equiv (P \vee Q)\implies R\\
      (P \implies R) \vee (P \implies R) \equiv (P \wedge Q)\implies R\\\\
      P \iff Q \equiv (P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies P)\\
      P \iff Q \equiv \neg P \iff \neg \neg Q\\
      P \iff Q \equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg Q \wedge \neg P)\\
      \neg (P \iff Q) \equiv P \iff \neg Q       
    \end{gather*}
  \end{multicols*}

  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution consists of using a `gather*` environment, with two embedded `aligned` environments. (In each of the two `aligned` groups, alignment is performed on the `\equiv` symbols.)

In order to make all equations fit inside the column while using `\small` -- not `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize` or, shudder, `\tiny` -- all one needs to do is to assign mathord status to the `\implies` symbols in the penultimate group of four equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol, amsmath, geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,margin = 0.4in}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt} % 1pt looks rather heavy...

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\begin{center}
\textbf{Logical Equivalences}
\end{center}
\small
\begin{gather*}
    P \wedge T \equiv P\\
    P \vee F \equiv P\\[3ex]
    P \vee T \equiv T\\
    P \wedge F \equiv F\\[3ex]    
    P \wedge P \equiv P\\
    P \vee P \equiv P\\[3ex] 
    \neg (\neg P) \equiv P\\[3ex]
    P \vee Q \equiv Q \vee P\\
    P \wedge Q \equiv Q \wedge P\\[3ex]
    (P \vee Q) \vee R \equiv P \vee (Q \vee R)\\
    (P \wedge Q) \wedge R \equiv P \wedge (Q \wedge R)\\[3ex]
    P \vee (Q \wedge R) \equiv (P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R)\\
    P \wedge (Q \vee R) \equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge R)\\[3ex]
    \neg (P \wedge Q) \equiv \neg P \vee \neg Q\\
    \neg (P \vee Q) \equiv \neg P \wedge \neg Q\\[3ex]  
    P \vee (P \wedge Q) \equiv P\\
    P \wedge (P \vee Q) \equiv P\\[3ex]
    P \vee \neg P \equiv T\\
    P \wedge \neg P \equiv F\\[3ex]
    \begin{aligned} 
    P \implies Q &\equiv \neg P \vee Q\\
    P \implies Q &\equiv \neg Q \implies \neg Q\\
    P \vee     Q &\equiv \neg P \implies Q\\
    P \wedge   Q &\equiv \neg (P \implies \neg Q)\\
    \neg (P \implies Q) &\equiv P \wedge \neg Q 
    \end{aligned} \\[3ex]
    (P {\implies} Q) \wedge (P {\implies} R) \equiv P {\implies} (Q \wedge R)\\
    (P {\implies} Q) \vee   (P {\implies} R) \equiv P {\implies} (Q \vee   R)\\
    (P {\implies} R) \wedge (P {\implies} R) \equiv (P \vee   Q){\implies} R\\
    (P {\implies} R) \vee   (P {\implies} R) \equiv (P \wedge Q){\implies} R\\[3ex]
    \begin{aligned}
    P \iff Q\phantom{)} &\equiv (P \implies Q) \wedge (Q \implies P)\\
    P \iff Q\phantom{)} &\equiv \neg P \iff \neg Q\\
    P \iff Q\phantom{)} &\equiv (P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg Q \wedge \neg P)\\
    \neg (P \iff Q) &\equiv P \iff \neg Q   
   \end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```